# Flex: Any way to use something like htmlText in Spark TextArea?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I´m using php services to insert text from MySql, to a TextArea. 
Ok, with mx textarea is working but how do i manage that with spark!?

this is my example with mx:

```
<mx:TextArea htmlText="{links.comment}"/>
```

this is an example with spark:

```
<s:TextArea>
    <s:textFlow>
        <s:TextFlow>
            <s:a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><s:span color="0xCECB02" textDecoration="none">Something and Something</s:span></s:a>
        </s:TextFlow>
    </s:textFlow>
</s:TextArea>
```

That works, but how can i take the same "{links.comment}" from MySql!?

Comment: <s:a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><s:span color="0xCECB02" textDecoration="none">{links.comment}</s:span></s:a>

Comment: thanks for the answer; but it doesn't work. I put {links.comment} inside the TextFlow tags and it give me the data from mysql but with all html tags!! Any other solution? Thanks again..

Comment: Try by using below code:- <s:TextArea color="0xCECB02" textDecoration="none" textFlow ="{TextFlowUtil.importFromString(links.comment, WhiteSpaceCollapse.PRESERVE)}"/> "or" <s:TextArea color="0xCECB02" textDecoration="none" textFlow ="{TextFlowUtil.importFromXML(links.comment as XML, WhiteSpaceCollapse.PRESERVE)}"/>

Comment: That's really great, Thanks a lot!! The "importFromString" is the right one. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting data as an tag format you can solve it by below way: -

```
<s:TextArea color="0xCECB02" textDecoration="none" textFlow ="{TextFlowUtil.importFromString(links.comment, WhiteSpaceCollapse.PRESERVE)}"/>
```